# Getting "no pg_hba.conf entry for host" when using sequelize-auto to generate models from a database on Heroku

Tags: postgresql, heroku, sequelize.js, sequelize-auto

I have a database on Heroku with some tables.

[image]

I have these config vars set for my app

I run this command with sequelize-auto to generate models from the database

```
sequelize-auto -h (host) -d (database) -u (user) -x (password) -p (port) --dialect postgres -c "./server/config/config.json" -o "./server/models"
```

Using these credentials
[image]

And I'm getting this

```
 error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host (my ip address), user (user), database (database), no encryption
```

At this point maybe it has something to do with my index.js or config.json in my local directory, but I don't see why it would affect anything. I just want to generate models from my database.

Here's my config.json

```
{
  "development": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": null,
    "database": "database_development",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "postgres"
  },
  "test": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": null,
    "database": "database_test",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "postgres"
  },
  "production": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": null,
    "database": "database_production",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "postgres"
  }
}
```

and my index.js

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];
const db = {};

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you